# Why don't all computers show in Net View?

Tags: networking, windows-10, cmd.exe, netbios, broadcast

This is for a Windows environment.

Either in a workgroup or domain environment, why don't all computers show up in Netview or Network (via Explorer)? Assuming all computers are online and pingable, what determines whether a computer shows up in Net View result? In some networks I see all devices and some only a few. Thanks.

Comment: this is very broad as written. SMB hosts announce their presence and offerings, so for one reason or other, the box you are using has not received announcements from the missing devices. This might be because of interstitial routers, SMB and NTLM and NetBIOS version differences, firewalling, switch congestion, broadcast traffic handling policies, power-save policies, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not every computers can be seen. Only those that enable [Network Discovery](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc181373.aspx) will appear in Explorer

[image: network discovery]

| Discovery State | Description |
| --- | --- |
| On | This state allows your computer to see other network computers and devices and allows people on other network computers to see your computer. This makes it easier to share files and printers. |
| Off | This state prevents your computer from seeing other network computers and devices and prevents people on other network computers from seeing your computer. |
| Custom | This is a mixed state in which some settings related to network discovery are enabled, but not all of them. For example, network discovery could be turned on, but you or your system administrator might have changed firewall settings that affect network discovery. |

[How to Turn On or Off Network Discovery in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/49652-turn-off-network-discovery-windows-10-a.html)